# ¿Como puedo instalar DEV C++ en Linux, paso a paso?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, c++11

estoy tratando de instalar Dev C++ en ubuntu pero no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo, las instrucciones que arrojan varios blog o foros son erróneas.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres instalar Dev C++? Si tienes la opción, te recomendaría que instales Code Blocks (el cual está disponible en el centro de descargas de Software de Ubuntu), o mejor aun Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Usar `wine` es una de esas opciones.

Answer (score 2):

Dev-C++ es un IDE diseñado para Windows, por lo que si quieres instalarlo en Linux, tienes básicamente dos opciones: o bien instalas Windows en una máquina virtual, cosa que creo que no es lo que buscas; o bien puedes instalar WineHQ, que es una re implementación de las llamadas al sistema de Windows, con lo que puedes correr aplicaciones Windows en Linux sin máquina virtual.

Según tu distribución, puedes instalar Wine desde el terminal con, por ejemplo `apt install wine`, o bien con `apt-get` en vez de `apt`, o con `dnf` para Fedora.

Sin embargo, los paquetes de wine que vienen en muchas distribuciones son muy antiguos, por lo que la mejor opción es ir a su página y descargar su última versión (la última estable es la 3.0) o compilar su código fuente en tu máquina.

Te dejo un enlace a su [página web](https://www.winehq.org/).

Tras su instalación, podrás instalar gran cantidad de aplicaciones de Windows en Linux, aunque algunas no funcionan, así que buena suerte.

Por otro lado, yo tampoco te recomendaría instalar Dev-C++ en Linux, ya que no te hace falta, hay IDEs mucho mejores, e incluso tu distribución viene con un compilador (gcc) mejor que el de Dev-C++ (antiguamente MinGW, ahora TDM), que repito, está hecho para Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo evitar Dev C++, ya que es obsoleto y su version para linux se encuentra en una version alpha desde hace 2 años.

Aun asi siempre puedes usar una gran variedad de IDEs y editores de texto para programar en C

CLion: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/

Eclipse: https://www.eclipse.org/

NetBeans: https://netbeans.org/

Vim: `sudo apt-get install vim`

Y no te olvides de instalar un compilador, aunque creo que GCC viene por defecto en ubuntu, puedes verificarlo escribiendo en la consola `gcc -v` o puedes instalar clang

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```